# How to use storage to upload a file without active record in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm a PHP programmer and I started to work with ROR recently.
In PHP+Laravel there is a quite convenient implementation to upload files, something like

```
Storage::disk('my_sftp_server')->put('hello.txt', 'Hello World');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem
Where **my_sftp_server** was set in the Laravel version of the **storage.yml** file.

As Laravel is strongly based on Rails, I think there should be a similar way to do it with Rails. But when I search for **Rails Storage** in google, all the results are related to ActiveStorage, and in my case my files are not directly related to my active records.

Is there some way to use the already set Rails storage to upload a file?

#### Reason:

I'm developing a shipping system and in the end of the day I need to create a consolidated report and save it in the carrier server using SFTP.

Comment: Is the file generated on the server or is it uploaded by the user?

Comment: Generated by server

Comment: Then just use [Net::FTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html) from the Ruby standard lib. ActiveStorage, Paperclip, etc. are completely irrelevant since they are for handling file uploads from the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write the `params` item to disk:

```
IO.copy_stream(params[:files][0].tempfile, local_filepath)
```

Comment: Hello Tallboy, thanks for the answer, but I need to upload the file in a external storage (a sftp server)

Answer (score 0):

What you asked is not good approach. Reason is simple, whenever you store in external storage you have to define various parameter like permission, keys etc.

Let me give you example, You are storing user documents for now, later you are storing different documents, image relevant to different object. Even if you deny to provide such relevance, Rails is fully based on object oriented programming. So you have to give object reference for whatever document you are storing, so you can retrieve it properly.

[Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) is one of the gem used for it.

To store it in local app path,

```
 @user.document.copy_to_local_file(nil, path)
```

Here in above document can be non-db field for user made by `attr_accessor`. `copy_to_local_file` is paperclip method.

Comment: Hello Ray, thank you for the response. Sorry I think I didn't well explained it. The files that I want to upload are not related to the object. It is a csv file with the consolidated data of the operations of the day

Comment: @AlanAlvesdeOliveira Question is you will save in external storage but how will you refer them or identify them ?

Comment: I will save the files as <current_time_stamp>.csv, after save it will not be necessary to refer its anymore